# $a = new PharData($tar_achive); cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x, phar

I get following error when loading builtin PharData PHP class in Cakephp3 Controller

```
Error: Class 'App\Controller\PharData' not found
```

I call PharData like this :

```
$a = new PharData($tar_achive);
```

(PharData class works when using it outside of Cakephp3 with simple php script)

How I can tell cakephp3 to use builtin PHP Class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use class with slash which will inform that it is built in PHP class

```
$a = new \PharData($tar_achive);
```

Comment: It's more about pointing to the global namespace, where all kinds of classes can live, not just PHPs built-in ones.